# hot to make a textView in a layout only scrollalbe not the whole layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, textview

I have several layouts in my xml layout in these layouts i have a textview which contain a big text. what i need ur help in is how to set only the textview to scroll vertically no the whole layout.
here is my xml layout

```
enter code here

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/inner_content"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/bg"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dip"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip"
    android:paddingRight="2dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sample_button"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
        android:layout_width="35dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/burger" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/home_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breakARTISTNAME"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="374dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#C71585" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/add_schedule_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add_button" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="add to my schedual"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/breakARTISTIMAGE"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    //here is the text i need only to be scrollalbe

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breakARTISTDESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/breakARTISTIMAGE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/breakARTISTIMAGE2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/breakARTISTDESCRIPTION"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/inner_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:paddingLeft="2dip"
        android:paddingRight="2dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sample_button"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
            android:layout_width="35dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/burger" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/home_button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/breakARTISTNAME"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="374dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#C71585">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/add_schedule_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/add_button" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="add to my schedual"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/breakARTISTIMAGE"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>


        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/breakSCROLLVIEW"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/breakARTISTIMAGE">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/breakARTISTDESCRIPTION"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        </ScrollView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/breakARTISTIMAGE2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/breakSCROLLVIEW"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It destroyed my layout look now the textView is all over the the relativeLayout while scrolling

Comment: @MostafaAddam: I have changed my answer. Please give it a try.

Comment: Thank youuuuu alott u saved me thumbs up

Comment: Bro one more thing now the scroll is working but my text is too long there are still some lines are not showing when the scroll reach the end what should i do

Comment: @MostafaAddam: I have made further changes in the layout but I think you will have to reduce your images to accommodate the layout in the screen.